# Does JBoss ESB Action has life cycle?

Tags: java, esb, jboss-esb

Does JBoss ESB Action has life cycle like Servlet does (init, service, destroy)?

I am writing dozens of ESB actions that requires the same initialization and destroy business logic. So I am thinking of putting this common init and destroy code in one parent class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, the JBoss ESB Action does have life cycle but the cycle is executed only once during initialization and not per request as I would have expected it to be.